# Handle "defaults" or placeholders in git repo

Tags: git, gitignore

In a git repository, I would like to have a folder `secrets/` with several text files. The text files' contents is placeholder/default text, that the user should change to his situation.

My question: is it possible to set up git in such a way, that the folder is part of the repository when initially cloned, yet so that any changes to it are not commited when the user pushes commits back up? Changes a user might make to this folder, but which should be excluded from a default `git add .` command:

- update contents of pre-existing files;
- delete pre-existing files;
- add new files;
- replace folder with symlink to out-of-repo private folder.

I tried adding `/secrets` (and `/secrets/` and `/secrets/*`) to `.gitignore`, but still file deletions are picked up on (i.e., not ignored). I also tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged` on each file, but it seems I must repeat that on each machine the repo gets cloned to.

Comment: Let me know if the linked dupe(s) don't answer your question